# What is the use of #if in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to know the usage of #if in C#...Thanks..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`#if` is a [pre-processor command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx).

It's most common usage (which some might say is an abuse) is to have code that only compiles in debug mode:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Here");
#endif
```

One very good use (as StingyJack [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989283/what-is-the-use-of-if-in-c/2989304#comment3051745_2989304)) is to allow easy debugging of a Windows Service:

```
static void Main()
{
#if (!DEBUG)
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new Service1() };
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#else
    // Debug code: this allows the process to run as a non-service.

    // It will kick off the service start point, but never kill it.

    // Shut down the debugger to exit

    Service1 service = new Service1();
    service.<YourServicesPrimaryMethodHere>();
    // Put a breakpoint on the following line to always catch
    // your service when it has finished its work
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#endif 
}
```

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DebugWinServices.aspx)

This means that running release mode will start the service as expected, while running in debug mode will allow you to actually debug the code.

Comment: Best use of #if that I have seen.... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DebugWinServices.aspx

Answer (score 4):

"When the C# compiler encounters an #if directive, followed eventually by an #endif directive, it will compile the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined"

Here's the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) link.

Answer (score 4):

`#if` has lost so much compared to its ancestors -- c or C++. nowadays I use `#if` for only two scenarios

1) use it to enable code for debug or not debug

```
#if DEBUG
    // code inside this block will run in debug mode.
#endif
```

2) use it to quickly turn off code

```
#if false
     // all the code inside here are turned off..
#endi
```

Answer (score 2):

[#if (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) is a compiler directive. See the MSDN article for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is used for Preprocessor Directives, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`#if` is a compiler directive, for example you can `#define test`

and later in the code you may test `#ifdef test` 
compile code block with `#ifdef`